# Cloud Foundry SSL with Cloud Flare

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudflare

I have an application in Cloud Foundry lets say `http://something.cfapps.io`. Also I purchased a custom domain lets say `http://mynewapp.com`. Currently, I am masking the custom domain to the domain from Cloud Foundry.

My question is, if I want to enable SSL in Cloud Flare which domain should I put as secured ? Is it the first one or second one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do both through our [SSL options](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-). I assume you're looking at something like Flexible SSL?

Comment: I read that Flexible SSL is less secure than Full SSL. Any reference on the Full (Strict) SSL guide ? And does it mean that I still need to purchase certificate else where ?

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step instructions for setting up SSL on a custom domain can be found here.

http://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/integrations/cloudflare/index.html

Basically this results in requests going to CloudFlare over HTTPS and being sent to your application over SSL via https://.cfapps.io.  This is the "Full SSL" option and it gives you end to end encryption.  What it doesn't give you is certificate checks and so despite it being very unlikely, it is technically susceptible to a man-in-the-middle attack.

The "Full SSL (strict)" option would eliminate the possibility of a man-in-the-middle style attack, however this doesn't work at the moment because the certificate check expects the incoming domain (i.e. your domain) to match the domain on the backend server's certificate, which it won't since your domain won't match ".cfapps.io".